# json cause crash - Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using Json with PHP to connect my android app with a remote mySql db.
but for some reason the JSON parser returns and error saying there's a problem with the json string.

The json string is: {"success":1,"message":"sit created."}

the error is: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of {"success":1,"message":"sit created."}

Can anyone tell me what the problem is, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is there a space before the {?

Comment: There's no space. the '{' is the first char

Comment: Problem solved, apparently there were some wired chars (not white spaces) that made the json string it self start from char index 2. the trim option also didn't work, so i used the substring method.